# Batch file to find USB drive and change drive letter

Tags: batch-file, winpe

I'm trying to automate our imaging process. We have multiple computer models with different images all stored on one USB drive with WinPE. I have gotten as far as creating a script that with give me options using `Choice` to select which computer I want to image but the problem is that depending on what computer I'm imaging the usb drive's letter changes. I'm looking to create a batch file that will find the USB drive and change the drive letter to say "X:" so that the `Choice` script can run properly with a static drive letter to look for the image files.

I search and found a script that will find the USB drive by name "Ace" and output the drive letter but havent been able to figure out how to take that drive and change it to "X:"

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart ^| findstr "Ace"') do (set Acedrive=%%A)
```

What I have so far is this:

```html
echo off
cls
Echo Image Selection Menu
Echo =======================
Echo 1 Dell D820
Echo 2 Dell E6510
Echo 3 Dell E6520
Echo 4 Lenovo T431S
Echo 5 Lenovo T440S
Echo 6 Lenovo M73 Tiny
Echo =======================
Choice /C 123456 /M "What computer are you trying to image?"
If Errorlevel 6 goto 6
If Errorlevel 5 goto 5
If Errorlevel 4 goto 4
If Errorlevel 3 goto 3
If Errorlevel 2 goto 2
If Errorlevel 1 goto 1

Goto End

:6
cls
imagex /apply M73.wim 1 g:
Goto End

:5
cls
imagex /apply T440S.wim 1 g:
Goto End

:4
cls
imagex /apply T431S.wim 1 g:
Goto End

:3
cls
imagex /apply E6520.wim 1 g:
Goto End

:2
cls
imagex /apply E6510.wim 1 g:
Goto End

:1
cls
imagex /apply D820.wim 1 g:
:End
```

So This basically just gives me options to choose what computer I'm imaging then runs the associated imagex command for that wim.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a batch file is not always the first choice...

Comment: @ThomasWeller - Batch is more than suitable for this.

Comment: @SomethingDark: then I understood it wrong, sorry. I thought he wanted to assign the USB stick a different drive letter like you can do in Windows' disk management ("Create and format hard disk partitions"), not just CD to it.

Comment: Thomas is correct actually. I'm trying to change the drive letter from whatever the computer assigns to it, to x:\. My Script is pointing to a certain drive but if the drive letter changes each time then the script wont work. Sorry for the confusion and thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try this code:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%A in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart ^| findstr "Ace"') do (
set Acedrive=%%B
(echo select volume %%A
echo assign letter=X) | diskpart
)
```

hope you find it helpfull.

Comment: Dude your a genius. Thank you so much! Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the little-known and even-less-frequently-used `/d` option of the `cd` command, which will move drives in addition to directories.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart ^| findstr "Ace"') do (set Acedrive=%%A)
cd /d %Acedrive%:\
```

Just remember to run the script as an administrator or else diskpart will open in a new window and the code won't work.

Comment: I'm trying to change the drive letter from whatever the computer assigns to it, to x:\. My Script is pointing to a certain drive but if the drive letter changes each time then the script wont work. Sorry for the confusion and thank you guys for the help

Comment: @Chris - That's exactly what my code does. It finds what drive has the string `Ace` in the name and changes the drive to that. How is that not what you want?

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to scripting. When I run the script it just changes the directory to that drive.  I'm looking to get it to change the usb drive from d: to x: or whatever other letter I choose. I want to reassign it. I know I can do diskpart and run the commands each time but im trying to make it unattended.

Comment: _Ohhh..._ I know of no way to do that. And frankly, unless you've got more than one drive with "Ace" in the title, it will work fine automatically.

Comment: I added what I have here to my original post. So what your saying is to add your code in before each imagex command to apply? That way it changes the directory to the usb correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this batch to find the drive letter of the connected USB key  :

```
@echo off
Mode con cols=98 lines=10 & Color 9E
Title Searching the Drive letter of your USB Key by Hackoo 2014
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
echo.
echo                           Searching the drive letter of your USB Key .......
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID,DriveType /Format:CSV > %Tmp%\tmp.txt 
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ('%COMSPEC% /a /c type "%Tmp%\tmp.txt"') do echo %%b %%c >> %Tmp%\tmp2.txt
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('%COMSPEC% /a /c type "%Tmp%\tmp2.txt" ^|Find "2"') Do (set MyUSBDrive=%%i)
Del %Tmp%\tmp.txt & Del %Tmp%\tmp2.txt
cls
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
echo.
echo                          The drive letter of your USB Key is  %MyUSBDrive%
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
pause
```

Comment: Hi Hackoo. I have found a script that will list what drive letter my USB drive is but what I was wondering is if there was another script to reassign a drive one one letter to another.